# Android get certificates public key

Tags: android, ssl, public-key

I want to get a certificates public key in a specific format, but I don't know how to do that. The format that I want it in is sha256/VRtYBz1boKOXjChfZYssN1AeNZCjywl77l2RTl/v380=.

This is what I have got so far:

```
String hostname = "api.github.com";
SSLSocketFactory factory = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(hostname, 443);
socket.startHandshake();

Certificate[] certs = socket.getSession().getPeerCertificates();
Certificate cert = certs[0];
PublicKey key = cert.getPublicKey();
```

This retrieves the public key in a long string, but I need it in the format that I have already mentioned.

Comment: So... now just run it through sha-256?

Comment: @MattClark How do I do that?